# how do I remaster livecd to get rid of installer?

Tags: ubiquity

I want to remaster the xenial ISO by unpacking the squashfs image, chrooting, running some commands and repacking it. So far this works but I don't know what commands to run in the chroot to disable the installation prompt. I would like the final ISO to drop to the usual text mode login prompt. What commands disable running the installation prompt?

Comment: @Terrance Thanks that helps to provide context for what I am trying to do. Unfortunately, nothing on that page describes how to disable the installer and autologin in xenial.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find the answer. Pretty simple when you know systemd controls everything:

```
systemctl disable ubiquity
systemctl disable lightdm
```